# Is it possible for a quadratic equation to have one rational root and one irrational root?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

> Is it possible for a quadratic equation to have one rational root and one irrational root?

Yes, a pretty straightforward question. Is it possible?

Comment: That's the good question.

Answer (score 63):

Yes; for example, the quadratic equation
$$x^2-\sqrt{2}x=0$$
has two solutions, namely $x=0$ (which is rational) and $x=\sqrt{2}$ (which is irrational).

However, if we only allow *rational coefficients* for our quadratic equation, then it is true that either both solutions are rational or both are irrational. Given rational numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $a\neq0$, the quadratic equation tells us that the solutions to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are
$$x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\quad x=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is irrational, then both of these numbers are irrational; if $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is rational, then both of these numbers are rational.

This property is particular to *quadratic* equations only. For example, the cubic equation
$$x^3-2x=0$$
has the solutions $x=0$, $x=\sqrt{2}$, and $x=-\sqrt{2}$, the first of which is rational and the latter two of which are irrational, even though all of its coefficients are themselves rational numbers. The explanation for this is that a quadratic polynomial over the rational numbers must either factor completely or be irreducible, while a higher-degree polynomial can factor *partially*. For example, the factorization of $x^3-2x$ into irreducible rational polynomials is
$$x^3-2x=(x-0)\cdot(x^2-2).$$

Comment: Another simple proof is that if $P$ is a rational degree-2 polynomial with a rational root $a$, then $P/(x-a)$ is a rational degree-1 polynomial: so there is another root and it is rational.

Answer (score 29):

The equation
$$
(x-a)(x-b)=0
$$
is a quadratic equation whose roots are $a$ and $b$.  If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational then there's the example you seek.

Expanding this, you get
$$
x^2 - (a+b)x + ab=0.
$$
The coefficient $a+b$ is not rational.  Nor is $ab$ unless $a=0$.

If the coefficients are rational then the usual formula for solving quadratic equations tells you that either both roots are rational or both are irrational.

Answer (score 10):

More generally, let 
$$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0,$$
where $n \ge 1$ and $a_n\ne 0$. 
Suppose  that at least $n-1$ of the (complex) roots of the equation $P(x)=0$ are rational. Then all the roots of $P(x)=0$ are rational if and only if  $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ is rational. (Here a multiple root is counted according to its multiplicity.)

This is because the sum of the roots is $-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$.

In particular, if the coefficients are rational and there are at least $n-1$ rational roots, then all roots are rational.

There are polynomials of degree $n$ with exactly $n-1$ rational roots. Use for example $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(n-1))(x-\sqrt{2})$. Such a polynomial necessarily has at least one irrational coefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the equation of form           x(x-a)=0
Here one solution is 0 and other is a. So if a is irrational one root is rational and other is irrational.